# Submit Form To Value Id

Tags: jquery

I'm sending this form to facebox however the value of the field name is not getting through. How can I submit the form with the value in the action url? (I'm sure there's a simpler way).

```
<form action="javascript: jQuery.facebox({ajax:'livescore/quickhistory.php'});"     id="search-form" method="post">
<div class="wrapper">
<input type="text" id="name" value="Gamer Look Up" onBlur="if(this.value=='')     this.value='Gamer Look Up'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Gamer Look Up' ) this.value=''"  />
<a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('search-form').submit()">Submit</a> </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do it in the form's action at all? You're using JavaScript to submit the form anyway. Wouldn't it be easier, when the user clicks that "submit" link, to instead look up that value and simply call $.facebox? Maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: yeah but the problem is facebox is looking for the value on the main browser. I'm trying to pass the value to facebox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what's going on between your form and facebox, but for starters, you should try moving all that behavioral code out of the inline event handlers:

```
$(document).ready( function(){

  $('#search-form').submit( function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // suppress default form handler
    $.facebox({...}); // add your code to presumably handle submission
  });

  $('#name') // a confusing ID, especially since you should add a "name" attr
    .focus( function(){ if( this.value == 'Look up' ) this.value = ''; } )
    .blur( function(){ if( this.value == '' ) this.value = 'Look up'; } );

  $('a#your-link-id').click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // suppress default link behavior
    $('#search-form').submit();
  });

});
```

Your HTML can then be simplified to:

```
<form action="/some_reasonable_default" id="search-form" method="post">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="name" value="Look Up" name="some-name" />
    <a href="#" id="your-link-id">Submit</a> 
  </div>
</form>
```

Note that you should add a `name` to your `<input>` field. If you want to have any ability to submit the form using the page's natural behavior (without the overriding JavaScript code), `name` and `value` are what your handler script will receive. You should also add an ID to the submit link, as in the example above, to make it easier to select unambiguously.

Comment: Thanks bro, but it's still not working. The value's not sent to facebox

Comment: maybe I shouldn't be using 

if(isset($_GET['glname']))
{
$name=$_GET['glname'];
}  

on the receiving page

Comment: There's obviously code we're not seeing. But are you submitting to the receiving page via `GET` or `POST`? If `POST`, then of course you'll find the submitted data in `$_POST['varname']`.

Comment: I went went around it, I first submitted the form to the database with a name value, they had the facebox page get the name value from the database.